# Related rate of change cone (missing values?)

Tags: calculus, volume

Grains of sands are falling and they form a cone with volume,V=1/3πr^2
 When the radius of the base of the cone is **10m**, the rate at which the radius is increasing is **2cm/s** while the rate at which the height is increasing is **1cm/s**.
Calculate the rate of change of the volume of the cone at this instant.

There is **no angle**, **no value of height** I can plug in, at this point I'm pretty sure that this question is missing some vital information.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please tell us what $r$ is. Also, it is strange that a volume is only depending on the square of a variable. Can you review those points ?

Comment: Yes, you will need some way of determining height.